Regex matches specific url patterns
I'm trying to find a list of urls matching the pattern. I have a string with a note which includes multiple URLs with distinct patterns.
Note example:
This is the list of link you need to solve the problem
http://customdomain.com/product/123 *new product*
https://customdomain.com/invoice/987
https://customdomain.com/product/45 (product to remove)
https://customdomain.com/product/999 
http://customdomain.com/invoice/741

This is my C# code to get the list of product URLs:
var pattern = @"(((http|https):\/\/customdomain\.com\/).*(\/product\/)(\d+))";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

I want to get a list of 3 product domains and matches result in 1 match only

Your use of .* after .com will likely cause you problems.

Regex might not be the right tool for this job. Consider using a URL parser (URI class, Flurl, etc).

.com\/) <-- This will match .com/ - while (\/product will match /product - so it will only match .com//product - which isn't what you want.

If you are looking for a solution not using Regex, probably you should look for Uri.Segments which is easier as @gunr2171 mentioned.

This works for me:
(?<scheme>.+?://)(?<host>[0-9a-z\-\.]+)(?<path>/product/(?<pid>\d+))

You'll need to run it in case-insensitive mode (i.e. with RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wDoIg6/2

const String INPUT_TEXT = @"

http://customdomain.com/product/123  *new product*
https://customdomain.com/invoice/987
https://customdomain.com/product/45 (product to remove)
https://customdomain.com/product/999 
http://customdomain.com/invoice/741

";

Regex regex = new Regex( @"(?<scheme>.+?://)(?<host>[0-9a-z\-\.]+)(?<path>/product/(?<pid>\d+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled );

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches( INPUT_TEXT );
foreach( Match m in matches )
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0}{1}{2} - {3}",
        /*0:*/ m.Groups["scheme"].Value,
        /*1:*/ m.Groups["host"  ].Value,
        /*2:*/ m.Groups["path"  ].Value,
        /*3:*/ m.Groups["pid"   ].Value
    );
}


Gives me this output:
http://customdomain.com/product/123 - 123
https://customdomain.com/product/45 - 45
https://customdomain.com/product/999 - 999


I guess you could improve performance if you narrow down the scheme to https?:// instead of using .+?:// (especially if the pattern is not anchored and these urls can occur anywhere in a string).

If I could, I would suggest using different tools for the job - regex for all is not best approach (sometimes maybe valid). Generally, it leads to very unreadable code, when you try to do everything you can with regex. And I think this is such example.
I don't like to do much parsing to "well known" stuff, which are URLs or HTML, XML, etc.
I would limit regex to what it really needs to do, so to extract from your note "candidates" for URLs.
For that we can use https?://\S+ pattern:

http part matches http literally,
s? matches s, but optionally,
:// matches :// literally,
\S+ matches one or more non-whitespace characters (so reads until the end of URL).

This way, we extract URL candidates, which we then try to parse as Uri with its constructor - having that, we later can leverage Uri class to do processing (extracting path, etc.).
Full example:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var note = @"This is the list of link you need to solve the problem
http://customdomain.com/product/123 *new product*
https://customdomain.com/invoice/987
https://customdomain.com/product/45 (product to remove)
https://customdomain.com/product/999 
http://customdomain.com/invoice/741";

    var simpleRegex = @"https?://\S+";
    var matched = Regex.Matches(note, simpleRegex);
    var productUrls = new List<Uri>();
    foreach (Match match in matched)
    {
        try
        {
            var validUri = new Uri(match.Value);
            var localPathParts = validUri.LocalPath.Split('/');
            if(localPathParts.Contains("product"))
                productUrls.Add(validUri);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}

